# WPF Rectangle filled with horizontal or vertical lines

Tags: wpf, drawing

I am trying to create one rectangle filled with Horizontal or Vertical lines.
The width of the rectangle is dynamic so I can not use an image brush.
Please let me know if anybody knows any solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out a straight-forward way of doing this; finally, I used following visual brush resources to fill rectangle with horizontal, vertical or dotted vertical lines respectively

```
   <!--for horizontal lines-->    
   <VisualBrush 
              x:Key="HorizontalLines" 
              TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,4,4" 
              ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,10,10"    
              ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 0 10 l 10 0" />
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>

        <!--For vertical lines-->
        <VisualBrush 
              x:Key="VerticalLines" 
              TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,4,4" 
              ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,10,10"    
              ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas >            
                    <Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 0 0 l 0 10" />                        
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>


         <!--For dotted vertical lines-->
        <VisualBrush 
                x:Key="DottedVerticalLinesWithFill" 
                TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,10,10" 
                ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,10,10"    
                ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Stroke="Purple" Data="M 0 5l 0 -10" />
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this with a LinearGradientBrush:

```
  <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100">
     <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Reflect" StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 0.05">
           <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Black"/>
           <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
```

You control line thickness and orientation with the EndPoint property.

Comment: This approach only works for shapes of fixed size (100x100 rectangle in above case). If shape can stretch, then the size of dashes will stretch as well. That's not what you want usually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a TileBrush?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, are you suggesting that I should use an ImageDrawing and DrawingBrush TileMode set to "Tile" ?

Comment: Set Stretch to Fill otherwise nothing will work since it will always use the image default size.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageBrush` derives from `TileBrush` so you can use the `Viewport` property to repeat the image. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport.aspx) for an example.

Comment: I am not able to visualize how this will work, the basic TileMode itself is not working for me here is a code snippet...

<Rectangle.Fill>                                   
 <ImageBrush  ImageSource="C:\Pravin\DrawRectangleWithLines\horizontalLine.JPG"  Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"  />                
</Rectangle.Fill>